# Google Play Services + Android Studio Emulator

Tags: android, google-maps, autocomplete, google-play-services

I recently have been facing this issue with Android Studio emulator and I don't undestand how and why it has appeared, because until now my emulator and app were working just fine.

Now when I try to run my app (which uses Google Map and Google Places Autocompletion) a message shows relating that Google Play Services wasn't  installed. I managed to install it on my emulator, but the app still doesn't work fine. The Google Map appears, but the Google Places autocompletion doesn't work anymore.

I noticed this is a common issue among Android developers and after some research i've been trying to adapt some solutions but the problem remains.

Can anyone help me to solve with this issue and explain to me why it happened? Is it because some Android Studio updates?

(Error messages)

```
    05-20 21:56:52.528: A/GmsApplication(2108): Unable to install secure provider, due to exception:

    05-20 21:56:52.528: A/GmsApplication(2108): java.lang.SecurityException: attempting to read gservices without permission: Neither user 10053 nor current process has com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES.

    05-20 21:56:52.528: A/GmsApplication(2108):     at android.app.ContextImpl.enforce(ContextImpl.java:1914)

    05-20 21:56:52.528: A/GmsApplication(2108):     at android.app.ContextImpl.enforceCallingOrSelfPermission(ContextImpl.java:1943)

    05-20 21:56:52.528: A/GmsApplication(2108):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.enforceCallingOrSelfPermission(ContextWrapper.java:600)

    05-20 21:56:52.528: A/GmsApplication(2108):     at com.google.android.gsf.f.c(SourceFile:107)

    05-20 21:56:52.528: A/GmsApplication(2108):     at com.google.android.gsf.f.a(SourceFile:121)

    05-20 21:56:52.528: A/GmsApplication(2108):     at com.google.android.gsf.f.a(SourceFile:227)

    05-20 21:56:52.528: A/GmsApplication(2108):     at com.google.android.gms.common.a.l.a(SourceFile:301)

    05-20 21:56:52.528: A/GmsApplication(2108):     at com.google.android.gms.common.a.e.a(SourceFile:219)

    05-20 21:56:52.528: A/GmsApplication(2108):     at com.google.android.gms.common.a.d.c(SourceFile:197)

    05-20 21:56:52.528: A/GmsApplication(2108):     at com.google.android.gms.common.a.d.d(SourceFile:208)

    05-20 21:56:52.528: A/GmsApplication(2108):     at com.google.android.gms.common.security.ProviderInstallerImpl.insertProviderGated(SourceFile:90)

    05-20 21:56:52.528: A/GmsApplication(2108):     at com.google.android.gms.common.app.GmsApplication.onCreate(SourceFile:84)

    05-20 21:56:52.528: A/GmsApplication(2108):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1012)

    05-20 21:56:52.528: A/GmsApplication(2108):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4556)

    05-20 21:56:52.528: A/GmsApplication(2108):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:151)

    05-20 21:56:52.528: A/GmsApplication(2108):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1364)

    05-20 21:56:52.528: A/GmsApplication(2108):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)

    05-20 21:56:52.528: A/GmsApplication(2108):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)

    05-20 21:56:52.528: A/GmsApplication(2108):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)

    05-20 21:56:52.528: A/GmsApplication(2108):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)

    05-20 21:56:52.528: A/GmsApplication(2108):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)

    05-20 21:56:52.528: A/GmsApplication(2108):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)

    05-20 21:56:52.528: A/GmsApplication(2108):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)


    05-20 21:56:52.552: D/AndroidRuntime(2108): Shutting down VM


    05-20 21:56:52.560: E/AndroidRuntime(2108): FATAL EXCEPTION: main

    05-20 21:56:52.560: E/AndroidRuntime(2108): Process: com.google.android.gms, PID: 2108

    05-20 21:56:52.560: E/AndroidRuntime(2108): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver com.google.android.gms.subscribedfeeds.ConfigurationReceiver: java.lang.SecurityException: attempting to read gservices without permission: Neither user 10053 nor current process has com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES.

    05-20 21:56:52.560: E/AndroidRuntime(2108):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2619)

    05-20 21:56:52.560: E/AndroidRuntime(2108):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1700(ActivityThread.java:151)

    05-20 21:56:52.560: E/AndroidRuntime(2108):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1380)

    05-20 21:56:52.560: E/AndroidRuntime(2108):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)

    05-20 21:56:52.560: E/AndroidRuntime(2108):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)

    05-20 21:56:52.560: E/AndroidRuntime(2108):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)

    05-20 21:56:52.560: E/AndroidRuntime(2108):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)

    05-20 21:56:52.560: E/AndroidRuntime(2108):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)

    05-20 21:56:52.560: E/AndroidRuntime(2108):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)

    05-20 21:56:52.560: E/AndroidRuntime(2108):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)

    05-20 21:56:52.560: E/AndroidRuntime(2108): Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: attempting to read gservices without permission: Neither user 10053 nor current process has com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES.

    05-20 21:56:52.560: E/AndroidRuntime(2108):     at android.app.ContextImpl.enforce(ContextImpl.java:1914)

    05-20 21:56:52.560: E/AndroidRuntime(2108):     at android.app.ContextImpl.enforceCallingOrSelfPermission(ContextImpl.java:1943)

    05-20 21:56:52.560: E/AndroidRuntime(2108):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.enforceCallingOrSelfPermission(ContextWrapper.java:600)

    05-20 21:56:52.560: E/AndroidRuntime(2108):     at com.google.android.gsf.f.c(SourceFile:107)

    05-20 21:56:52.560: E/AndroidRuntime(2108):     at com.google.android.gsf.f.a(SourceFile:121)

    05-20 21:56:52.560: E/AndroidRuntime(2108):     at com.google.android.gsf.f.a(SourceFile:182)

    05-20 21:56:52.560: E/AndroidRuntime(2108):     at com.google.android.gms.subscribedfeeds.ConfigurationReceiver.onReceive(SourceFile:31)

    05-20 21:56:52.560: E/AndroidRuntime(2108):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2612)

    05-20 21:56:52.560: E/AndroidRuntime(2108):     ... 9 more
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to run the app on an emulator that has Google APIs on it, it's an option when you create the emulator. Just choose the target with Google APIs, See the image below:

[image: AVD Screenshot]

Comment: I already tried that and the problem persists. Should I try with a lower API level? I'm using level 22(lolipop)...

Comment: Doesn't hurt to try another emulator, yes

Comment: And also if you can copy and paste the error message here

Comment: I think there's a permission you need to declare in the manifest. Did you declare all needed permissions ?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have Google Play Services installed to your app too. Add the following dependencies in your `build.gradle` file if you have not already done that:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.3.0'
}
```

After doing this Save the changes and click Sync Project with Gradle Files  in the toolbar.

If you are accessing the Google Play Services features, it is strongly encouraged to use the [GoogleApiClient](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/GoogleApiClient.html) class.  To detect if the device has the appropriate version of the Google Play services APK, implement the onConnectionFailed() callback method. If the connection fails due to a missing or out-of-date version of the Google Play APK.

For Autocomplete API not working check the API_KEY is added to the manifest file also, call GeoDataApi.getAutocompletePredictions() passing a query in form of a string and also LatLngBounds. For more information refer to the following [documentation](https://developers.google.com/places/android/autocomplete).